# Unable to search using SearchView in ActionBar

Tags: android

I have a SearchView in actionbar but when I type something in, I can't get the results to be filtered from my ListFragment.

I've been trying to look for some answers but I can't seem to get it right. Can anyone please give me a hand please? The relevant code is below.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.szen95.meddict;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new SearchFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0f);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem( R.id.search_bar ).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo( getComponentName() ) );

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

                   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
 }
```

SearchFragment:

```
package com.example.szen95.meddict;

/**
 * Created by szen95 on 6/15/15.
 */

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class SearchFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/drugclasses.json";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";
    private static final String TAG_CODING_SYSTEM = "codingSystem";
    private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";



    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray data = null;
//    ArrayAdapter<String> mConditionsAdapter;

    public SearchFragment() {
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
//        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView lv = getListView();

//        Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
//                getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String code = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),Details.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CODE, code);

                startActivity(in);
                Log.d("SearchFragment", "Data shown");

            }
        });

        new GetData().execute();
//        return v;
    }


    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    data = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        String code = c.getString(TAG_CODE);
                        String codingSystem = c.getString(TAG_CODING_SYSTEM);
                        String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        data.put(TAG_CODE, code);
                        data.put(TAG_CODING_SYSTEM, codingSystem);
                        data.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
                        data.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        dataList.add(data);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), dataList,
                    R.layout.list_item_search, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_CODE}, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.code});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
//        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
//
//
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you filtering stuff?

Comment: @shkschneider As the ListFragment is part of the MainActivitiy, I think I should be filtering stuff from the MainActivity then? I am new to Android development, I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarActivity is deprecated, use AppCompatActivity instead.

Check out this [sample project](https://github.com/Max64/android-toolbar-search) for search functionality in ToolBar/ActionBar

Comment: Good point, but solves nothing since the filtering is the problem here.

Comment: You should create search menu item in SearchFragment and call adapter.filter() method after user searches, again look at sample code

Comment: Pointing out `adapter.getFilter().filter()` is now a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually filter your content.

This is how I filter from the `Activity`:

```
        final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        if (mSearchMenuItem == null) {
            return true;
        }
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
        if (mSearchView == null) {
            return true;
        }
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                myFragment.search(query);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Key part is the `SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener` than runs `myFragment.search(query)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've tried using this way but I can't seem to get it to work in my OnCreateOptionsMenu method in the MainActivity...

Comment: That code was to inspire, not for copy-paste. At least explain what did not work please. With that code you just need to implement a `myFragment.search()` function that filters your `Adapter`...

Comment: I'm sorry for not saying what did not work. As I am completely new to programming, it is difficult as I myself am not sure about what goes on sometimes, so for something easy to you, it might be very difficult for me. For starters, I don't know how to filter the Adapter like you just said.

Comment: Fine. But you definitely need to learn and follow official guides first before asking a question for which you cannot understand the answer ^^ I cannot help more, sorry.